# python unittest failing assertion with overloaded __repr__

Tags: python, unit-testing, repr

In my code, I've defined a class with its own repr method. The representation of the class should be a list.

```
def __repr__(self):
    if self.front <= self.tail:
        q = self._queue[self.front:self.tail+1]

    elif self.front > self.tail:
        q = self._queue[self.front:]
        q.extend(self._queue[:self.tail + 1])

    return (q.__repr__())
```

I've written the following unittest to test this method.

```
def test_enqueue(self):
    q = BoundedQueue(1)
    q.enqueue(1)
    self.assertEqual(q, [1])
```

However, I end up with an assertion error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_internmatch_queue.py", line 13, in test_enqueue
    self.assertEqual(q, [1])
AssertionError: [1] != [1]
```

I'm not sure what the problem is... to my human eyes, [1]==[1]! I've tried several other variations in my repr method (below), and they all returned errors as well.

```
return repr(q)
return str(q)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`q` is a `BoundedQueue`.  `[1]` is a `list`.  They can't be equal unless you override `__eq__`.  `repr` is not used for equality testing.

Comment: This doesn't explain how to fix the problem. __repr__ wasn't used for equality testing, it is simply part of the class. Can anyone clarify HOW to deal with executing an equality test if your class has a __repr__ method?

Comment: Override `__eq__`, like I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

As recursive states, `__repr__` isn't used to detect whether two values are equal.

You have several options:

1. Define `__eq__` which is what python calls to check equality. I don't recommend this as I don't really see a BoundedQueue as being equal to a list
2. Define an `items()` method which returns the list. Then check for equality against the list
3. Add a way to build a BoundedQueue from a list. Then write `__eq__` to check for equality between two BoundedQueues.